# If I randomly select 6 books, what is the probability I...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have 30 books. 5 are labeled classics, 10 are labeled mysteries, 7 are labeled science, and the rest are sports. If I randomly select  6 books, what is the probability I

a) select at least 2 science books 
b) only select books that are mysteries or sports books
c) select books with precisely 2 being classics and 1 being science.

---

To me I am reading this as a multinomial coefficient problem where Big Omega is 30! / (5!*10!*7!*8!), I am confused on how to think of calculating my event A where I select at least 2 science books. Any suggestions on how I should proceed? Thank you!

Comment: It's  "Multinomial coefficient."  Did you get mis-autocorrected?

Comment: Yes I did. Thank you! I have corrected it.

Comment: Hint (for a.):  The probability of getting at least $2$ science books is $1-P(0)-P(1)$, where $P(i)$ is the probability of getting exactly $i$ science books.  Can you compute $P(0),P(1)$?

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting $6$ books from $30$, without bias, so you just need binomial coefficient for this.

$$\lvert \Omega\rvert = \binom{30}{6}$$

For (a) the favoured event, $A$, is of *at least* $2$ from $7$ science books (among these $6$ selected books).   It seems easier to count this through complements.

$$\lvert A\rvert ~=~ \lvert \Omega\rvert- \binom{7}{1}\binom{23}{5}-\binom{7}{0}\binom{23}{6}$$

---

Can you now complete this and do the rest?

Comment: I think I can complete the rest just fine. Would it be inappropriate for me to share what I did for part C to make sure my logic is sound?

Comment: @John That should be fine.